# Kubernetes way or Operator to clone PV between namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc, longhorn

Please tell me the best way to clone PV between namespaces.
I [read](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-pvc-datasource/) that cloning is only possible in a single namespace.

So far the best way I see is to explicitly copy the files from one folder to another after creating the PVC.

But I would like to create one PV and use it as a template for deployments.
I use Longhorn for disk management.

Thanks.

Comment: This could [help](https://github.com/longhorn/longhorn/issues/1815).

Comment: @gohm'c Thanks. Just tried. It is not working. New mysql-clone pvs has 0 Bytes

Answer (score 0):

Such functionality is not yet supported. There is some work done ([Add proposal for transfer of VolumeSnapshot #2849](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/2849)
) for similar feature, but it's not yet ready.

As of today, explicitly copying files is your best bet.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why @gohm'c says that is possible? https://longhorn.io/docs/1.2.3/snapshots-and-backups/csi-volume-clone/

Comment: Longhorn is 3rd party block storage solution. My answer relates to just kubernetes. Should have specified that.

Comment: Understood. I know that. Thanks